# keyboard layout problem

Tags: raspbian-buster

I recently downloaded the latest raspbian OS and then applied the SD card.  But I found an error while setting the keyboard-confiuration. that is in a different language setting maybe Spain language or Russian ! ( as you know default language is english.. )

I teach the Elementary school from the South Korea, so i set the Korean keyboard layout. but in the keyboard-configuration "South Korean" words translated others language words..

How to solve this problem?

[image: keyboard layout setting]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I noticed there was something completely screwy in the last buster image like this; I had to set the keyboard manually in `/etc/default/keyboard` as this screen did not hold any remotely normal options.  Try running `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade` to see if this is an issue that's been fixed.

Comment: My Raspbian system was speaking French in `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` with too many unprintable characters so there's something very broken in that package. I used the same method as @goldilocks to get round that.

Comment: I already tried ```sudo apt update``` ```sudo apt upgrade``` but problem not fixed
@goldilocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a same problem.
I solved the problem by manually edit `/etc/default/keyboard` and reboot PI.

Here is my keyboard config for korean:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="kr"
XKBVARIANT="kr104"
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```